# How to send json payload as HTTP OPTIONS response body?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, aws-api-gateway, http-method

The HTTP `OPTIONS` method is supposedly used to determine what other methods the server supports on a given resource. Given that, I have questions:

I have a `GET` API having certain parameters and I want to provide some information about the parameters (ex:their usage,type) in the preflight request.

Suppose, I have the following endpoint:

```
/v1/pets/?limit=10&page=1&birth_year=2013
```

and I want to provide the usage information (format,type,etc) about the parameters `limit`,`page` and `birth_year` in the `OPTIONS` response body.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to send a `json` payload in response to `OPTIONS` request?
- How can that be achieved using **AWS API Gateway**?

Comment: Response bodies in OPTIONS are allowed, but it might also be a good idea to just provide a information in a different resource (and refer to it via for example a Link header).

Comment: can you provide steps to achieve this in aws api gateway? what do you mean by **a different resource**?

Comment: It's typically better to publish specifications (formats, parameters) simply under a different url and have it accessible via a GET request. This is a different resource. I don't have a AWS or Lambda example for you, hence I didn't post this as an answer.

Comment: In that case, if response bodies are allowed in `OPTIONS`, why should an overhead to call a separate api done when the information can be provided in the preflight request itself.What are the drawbacks?